# jQuery blocking button on specific condition

Tags: jquery, button, conditional-statements, href, block

I have created something like this to block the button when countdown has ended. The result

```
    if($(".stm_countdown div").hasClass(".countdown_ended")) {
     $('.vc_general').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
     });
    }
```

Question, why this code is not working?

https://jsfiddle.net/0dg2vL1z/3/

What am I missing ;-) ?

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

**First**, you should bind your click event outside the condition.  Then check for your condition inside the function.

**Second**, you should look for `hasClass("classname")`, not `hasClass(".classname")`.

```
$('.vc_general').click(function(e) {
  if ($(".stm_countdown div").hasClass("countdown_ended")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Button is blocked");
    return false;
  }
});
```

[Link to updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bLbef2yg/1/).

Answer (score 1):

It's the dot in hasClass(). Instead it should be this:

`$(".stm_countdown div").hasClass("countdown_ended")`

Also you did not have jQuery included in your jsFiddle. Working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/pe0vo484/1/